# Parse Django HttpResponse in python

Tags: python, django

I have a function `getCode` that is called from ajax and returns `HttpResponse(json.dumps({'code': 2}))`. I have one case where this function is called from inside another Python function in an effort to stick to DRY. I am trying to access the HttpResponse in an `if` statement in this other function like so:

```
x = getCode(request)
if x['code'] == 2:
    # do stuff
```

How do I parse the HttpResponse object in Python so that I can access the data within as a dict?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really sound good and correct to have an overhead of creating an `HttpResponse` and to call the view from other python function. A code design and structure problem here.

Extract the logic that produces the data in the view into the separate function:

```
def my_view(request):
    data = get_data()
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), mimetype='application/json')
```

Then, call the function directly, not the view:

```
x = get_data()
if x['code'] == 2:
    ...
```

This way you would not need to first dump the data to `JSON`, make an `HttpResponse`, load the response content into the python data structure again.

Hope that makes sense for you.

Answer (score 0):

Its a dict access it like this:

```
if x['code'] == 2:
```

Answer (score 0):

First get request.

```
x = getCode(request)
```

Convert the response to string.

```
string_data = r.getresponse().read().decode("utf-8")
```

Convert the string to dict.

```
dict_data = json.loads(string_data)
```